# static::$property in trait returns data bound to the trait instead of class

Tags: php, static, static-members, traits, late-static-binding

I was wondering what the `static` keyword returns in a trait? It seems like it's being bound to the trait and not the class that uses it. For example:

```
trait Example
{
    public static $returned;

    public static function method()
    {
        if (!eval('\\'.get_called_class().'::$returned;')) {
            static::$returned = static::doSomething();
        }   

        return static::$returned;
    }

    public static function doSomething()
    {
        return array_merge(static::$rules, ['did', 'something']);
    }
}

class Test {}

class Test1 extends Test
{
    use Example;

    protected static $rules = ['test1', 'rules'];
}

class Test2 extends Test
{
    use Example;

    protected static $rules = ['test2', 'rules'];
}

// usage

Test1::method();
// returns expected results:
// ['test1', 'rules', 'did', 'something'];

Test2::method();
// returns unexpected results:
// ['test1', 'rules', 'did', 'something'];
// should be:
// ['test2', 'rules', 'did', 'something'];
```

I could get it work with some nasty `eval()` in the `method()` method:

```
public static function method()
{
    if (!eval('\\'.get_called_class().'::$returned;')) {
        static::$returned = static::doSomething();
    }   

    return static::$returned;
}
```

Now it simply matches it against `\My\Namespaced\Class::$returned` but it is also weird as as checking a static property, `$returned`, which was defined in the trait to begin with and was bound correctly to the class that uses it. Then why won't the `static::$returned` work?

The PHP version is 5.6.10.

Comment: There's an example in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) that confirms your findings. What more do you wish to know?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where? I've read through this and can't find it

Comment: Press Ctrl+F and type in "static"....

Comment: you are missing `function` keywords in function definition.

Comment: @pinkalvansia that was a mistake, the real code has the `function` keyword. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no reference that say that the `static` keyword is bound to the trait and not the class that uses the trait.

Comment: @kfirba I am getting expected output!!

Comment: @pinkalvansia how is that possible? that's super weird.. Is there way to `var_dump` what the static keyword is?

Comment: Look at the example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well yea, the example says the exact opposite of my findings. The example is what I expect to happen but something else happens. What could possibly interfere? Maybe if the class that uses the trait is extending another class is may cause a bug?

Comment: I guess the difference is between function-`static` and member-`static`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I think you're on to something. There's an explanation of trait 'contexts' here that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935557/2137316. I suspect when you call a static method defined in the trait, you're talking to the trait, not the class using it. Meaning what you get back is the initialization value. I'd bet if you overrode the "method()" in Test2, you'd get the value you're expecting. I'd also bet if you gave that property a default value, Test1::method() would seem to ignore the reassignment just as Test2 is. Only a guess though, I haven't tested the theory.

Answer (score 0):

so why u use late static binding here?

try this

```
trait Example
{
    public static $returned;

    public static function method()
    {
        if (!self::$returned) {
            self::$returned = self::doSomething();
        }   

        return self::$returned;
    }

    public static function doSomething()
    {
        return array_merge(self::$rules, ['did', 'something']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because in my real code the classes that uses the traits are extending another class

Comment: so what? then show us you real code. examples youve posted should work fine

Comment: @M0rtiis You are right. I've updated the code in the question it-self. I wonder why I get this unexpected result..

Comment: check once more. subject. inheritances and recieved results

Comment: BTW. late static binding will have sense only if you ll use trait on Test and not on Test1 and Test2